# Magento2.2.2 Order email confirmation after switched back on sends old order confirmation email

Tags: magento2.2.2, order-email, magento-cron

Order email Communications has been switched Off for long period of time as the emails was being sent outside of magento.

However I notice while testing that if switched back On Old order emails stated sending I think this is due the cron job.

My question what should one do to stop it when switched back On?

Should I clear cron_schedule table; maybe update `sales_order` field: `email_sent`, `send_email`

I can see this fields is `sales_order` have the following values:
`email_sent: NULL`
`send_email: 1`

Set `send_email` to 0 will it stop cron job to trigger email for this orders ?

Any suggestions ?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

My findings was that asynchronous sending was `On` and while email communications was turned Off the values of field `email_sent` and `send_email` should have been set to `NULL` just as it is on
`sales_shipment` table.

When email communications is turned off and asynchronous sending is On next time you switch email communications back on be sure to update the fields `email_sent` and `send_email` or and turn off asynchronous sending.

There is also a report bug on asynchronous sending :https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27039

Thanks.